# How to iterate gridview or listview using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

how do i know from the client side that how many rows are there for gridiview or listview except header row.

Comment: your data control is rendered in browser as html table so by counting the no of rows ie tr you can get how many rows has been binded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
var number_of_rows = $("#<%=GridView1.ClientID %> tr").size();
```

Answer (score 1):

Every component has to generate HTML. So once you have those elements, you can easily count them like anything else.

Let's say, that your listview generates li elements with class 'a'. Then you can do:

```
$('.a').length; // returns count of elements with class 'a'
```

Edit: You don't even need jQuery for this, you can use [**pure javascript solution** (example).](http://jsfiddle.net/balron/xsaBN/)

```
var table = document.getElementById("abc");
var rows= table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
alert(rows.length)
```

for following markup:

```
<table id="abc">
    <tr><td>abc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>abc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>abc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>abc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>abc</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It's wrong. `length` is a property, not a method. You should use `.size()` or `.length`

Comment: @Edgar Villegas Alvarado: Thanks for poining that out. I have fixed it.